# firebase is not connection with flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

what is the problem ?
the loading widget is working after that not Connection widget is running
how I can solve this problem

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'; import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; import 'package:marwa_app/component/myResponsiveLibrary.dart'; import 'package:marwa_app/component/Logo.dart'; import 'package:marwa_app/component/MyDrawer.dart'; import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart'; import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'; import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class Reporting extends StatefulWidget {   @override  
_ReportingState createState() => _ReportingState(); }

class _ReportingState extends State<Reporting> {   final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();   final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  BoxDecoration boxDecoration() {
    return BoxDecoration(
      color: MainModel().mainColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.15),
          spreadRadius: 5,
          blurRadius: 5,
          offset: Offset(2, 2), // changes position of shadow
        ),
      ],
    );   }

  TextStyle titleStyle() {
    return TextStyle(
        color: MainModel().whiteColor,
        fontSize: MainModel().setFont(MainModel().largeFont, getWidth()));   }

  TextStyle textStyle() {
    return TextStyle(
      color: MainModel().whiteColor,
      fontSize: MainModel().setFont(MainModel().middleFont, getWidth()),
    );   }

  double getWidth() {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;   }

  final _name = TextEditingController();   final _phone = TextEditingController();   final _emType = TextEditingController();  double lat;   double lon;   bool _initialized = false;   bool _error
= false;

  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }   }

  @override   void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();   }   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_error) {
      return notConnection();
    }
    if (!_initialized) {
      return Loading();
    }
    return isConnection();   }

  Widget isConnection() {
    final widthScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: MainModel().mainColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff323266),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.notifications_active,
                color: MainModel().thirdColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () => {}),
          title: Logo(),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            Builder(
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: MainModel().thirdColor,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
                tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        endDrawer: Drawer(
          child: MyDrawer(),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MainModel()
                  .setPadding(MainModel().largePadding, widthScreen)),
          children: [
            Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Directionality(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        decoration: boxDecoration(),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _name,
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          autofocus: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintStyle: textStyle(),
                              hintText: 'الاسم الرباعي'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return "يرجى ادخل الاسم";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: MainModel().setPadding(
                              MainModel().middlePadding, widthScreen)),
                    ),
                    Directionality(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        decoration: boxDecoration(),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _phone,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          autofocus: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintStyle: textStyle(),
                              hintText: 'رقم الهاتف'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return "يرجى ادخال رقم الهاتف";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: MainModel().setPadding(
                              MainModel().middlePadding, widthScreen)),
                    ),
                    Directionality(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        decoration: boxDecoration(),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _emType,
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          autofocus: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintStyle: textStyle(),
                              hintText: 'نوع الابلاغ'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return "يرجى ادخال نوع الابلاغ (الحالة)";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: MainModel().setPadding(
                              MainModel().middlePadding, widthScreen)),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                            bool isLocationServiceEnabled =
                                await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
                            if (isLocationServiceEnabled == true) {
                              Position position =
                                  await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
                                      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
                              lon = position.longitude;
                              lat = position.latitude;
                            } else {
                              print(
                                  'امنح التطبيق من الوصول الى موقع... ثم اعد الارسال');
                            }
                          },
                          child: Image.asset('images/location.png')),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: MainModel().setPadding(
                                MainModel().largePadding * 2, widthScreen))),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Firebase.initializeApp();
                        if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          // save data in firebase

                          FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('Data')
                              .doc()
                              .set({
                            'name': _name,
                            'phone': _phone,
                            'em-type': _emType,
                          });

                          scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                              content: Text('تم ارسال بياناتك .... '
                                  'سيتم التواصل معك من الجهات المختصة')));
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('ارسال'),
                    )
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ));   }

  Widget notConnection() {
    final widthScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: MainModel().mainColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff323266),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.notifications_active,
                color: MainModel().thirdColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () => {}),
          title: Logo(),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            Builder(
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: MainModel().thirdColor,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
                tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        endDrawer: Drawer(
          child: MyDrawer(),
        ),
        body: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: MainModel()
                    .setPadding(MainModel().largePadding, widthScreen)),
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('not Connection of Database'),
                ),
              )
            ]));   }

  Widget Loading() {
    final widthScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: MainModel().mainColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff323266),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.notifications_active,
                color: MainModel().thirdColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () => {}),
          title: Logo(),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            Builder(
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: MainModel().thirdColor,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
                tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        endDrawer: Drawer(
          child: MyDrawer(),
        ),
        body: Container(
    child: Center(
        child: Text('Loading'),
        ),
    )
    );   } }
```

I don't have any error on compiler but not connected firebase.
just I want to take data from textfeild and saved in firebase.
my data is (name, phone, location, type of emergency).

Comment: Please isolate the problem. If the problem is in saving a value to the database, you shouldn't need any UI elements to reproduce it. If the problem is in reading a value from the UI, you should be able to reproduce it without Firebase. The more you can isolate the problem yourself, the more likely it is that someone can help you find its cause. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem just I can't connect between my app and firebase .
If the firebase isn't connected return not connect widget that return everytime
If the firebase is loading return a loading widget just to loading app
But connect widget is not working because no connect on firebase
Hope you have understood me to help me how to solve the problem

Comment: Also as commented as Frank, I think that you should not make tests relying on the UI, please could you log the requests and connections being made into the console? (also please add an example trying to get and put data with the result messages as this will be useful for us in order to identify the main issue (error messages will tell us why is not connecting or what is missing)